Block decomposition of equivariant maps using Wedderburn-Artin theorem
Let $K$ be a field, $A$ an Artinian simple $K$-algebra with minimal left ideal $M$.
We can view $M$ as a simple $A$-module, so $D^{op}:=\text{End}_A(M)$ is a $K$-division algebra by Schur's lemma. Additionally, for every primitive idempotent $e$ of $A$, $Ae \cong M$ and $eAe \cong eM \cong D$ as rings due to the Wedderburn-Artin theorem.
Consider a linear representation of $A$ into the algebra of $K$-endomorphisms of $M^n$:$$\rho: A \to \text{End}_K(M^n).$$
We have the algebra isomorphism $$\text{End}_A\left(M^n\right)\cong \text{Mat}_n\left(\text{End}_A(M)^{op}\right)=\text{Mat}_n(D).$$

My questions:
Suppose we identify $\text{End}_K(M^n)$ with $\text{Mat}_{n \dim_D(M)}(D)$. Is it true that, for every $\tau \in \text{End}_K(M^n)$, $$\rho(e) \tau \rho(e)=A \otimes I_{\dim_D(M)} \text{ for some }A \in \text{Mat}_n(D)?$$
Suppose we identify $\text{End}_K(M^n)$ with $\text{Mat}_{n \dim_K(M)}(K)$. Is it true that, for every $\tau \in \text{End}_K(M^n)$, $$\rho(e) \tau \rho(e)=A \otimes I_{\dim_D(M)} \text{ for some }A \in \text{Mat}_{n\dim_K(D)}(K)?$$
